# How to use VBS to program 1) windows media player? 2) your computer in general?

Tags: vbscript

I would like to open my video using VBS and So far I have this and it works fine

```
Set wmp = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
wmp.openPlayer("C:\Users\myvideo.mp4")
```

I would also like to add one more line to make it full screen.  How would one do that?

Also, my second question is probably more useful.

Is there a collective website to describe how to manipulate these objects?

When I played around with Matlab, I can at least press tab and see what can options are available under that object and I learned a lot that way (the website was also very helpful).

Is there a comparable way in VBS or for example, where can I find a extensive lists of command I could send to WM Player?

Thanks!

Comment: I would start with the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee487167.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For switching the window to a full screen window you have to use **Alt+Enter**. This can be done using sendKeys method of the Shell object. Here's the code:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "%{ENTER}"
```

Hope this suits you need. For further help check the [documentation](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.aspx) for SendKeys.